# Namespace the contents of a file, but without increasing indent

Tags: ruby

When you want to namespace a bunch of classes in ruby, you typically do:

```
# my_namespace.rb

module MyNamespace

  class ClassOne
    # ...
  end

  class ClassTwo
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

which has the unfortunate side effect of increasing the indent level of all the code in the file.  I'd much rather be able do something like issue a directive at the top of the file which effectively said, "*everything in this file should be in the `MyNamespace` module*".

Is this possible?

**NOTE:** I'm aware I could just keep the `module` wrapping but *not* indent everything, but that solution is unacceptable imo.

Comment: You could do `class MyNamespace::ClassOne`

Comment: Good point.  Not ideal, but the extra verbosity of every class name is arguably a lesser evil than the extra indent level.  I'll accept that answer if no one chimes in with something better.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why is adding a level of indention a problem? I would argue that the level of indentation helps to understand und read the code.

Comment: @spickermann: git noise, I assume. This _will_ cause conflicts.

Comment: @spickermann I'm trying to solve the problem of unnecessary indentation.  I completely disagree with your argument.  How does having an entire file indented help with clarity?  Namespacing a file should not require syntactically wrapping that entire file in a nested structure.  It's just a terrible design decision.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation level of the code is a function of an editor/ide.  The simple answer is:  Don't indent the code.

It is only a visual aspect, the level of scope is increased, regardless of the visual effect.

This can be avoided through taking advantage of different syntax, like using the scope operator as Sergio Tulentsev mentioned.

You could use eval and read in a file, but I think that would be terrible, though it would fix the indentation "problem".

```
module General
  module_eval "class One end"
  module_eval "class Two; p 'Done creating Two'; def self.report(); 'I am in General::Two' ; end; end"

  module_eval File.read('three.rb')
end

p General::Two.report
p General::Three.new.report
```

As a separate file, `three.rb`

```
class Three
  def report
    "This is #{self.class} and has #{self.class.ancestors}"
  end
end
```

But apparently nothing really reasonable for keeping the indentations away.

I do find it as a helpful tool visually to track scope when reading, based on indentation, so having 2, 4. 6 spaces or 8 spaces as indentation really doesn't seem like much of a pain.  Having 8 spaces (tab representation) at each level would be a lot more irritating as things flow off to the right of the screen.

Answer (score -3):

[Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) will tell you what to do according to the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)!

Edit:

```
# my_namespace.rb

module MyNamespace

class ClassOne
  # ...
end

class ClassTwo
  # ...
end

# ...
end
```

Causes this Rubocop warning:

`Warning:13:1: C: Incorrect indentation detected (column 0 instead of 2).`

Comment: Please take the time to read the original post.  I address this issue specifically in the last paragraph, and state that simply not indenting is not an acceptable solution.   So, rubucop agrees with me, and this "solution" was one I already said should not be considered....

Comment: This is describing the "you typically do:" part of the original post, and reinforcing that as well.

Comment: There is no such directive in Ruby AFAIK. In C++ `using namespace std;` is discouraged by e.g. Googles C++ Style guide favoring a block with no indentation. Maybe the upcoming officiel C++ style guide will favor no block.